# How to get POJO response using projection in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

I have a class `Student` which has one-to-many dependency with the `Department` class.

```
class Student{
    String name;
    int age;

    @OneToMany
    List<Department> departments;

    //all getter setters here
}
```

This is the `Department` class:

```
class Department{
    String depName;
    String address;
    //all getters and setters.
}
```

I am using Hibernate to fetch the result from a database.

I want to get `name`, `age` from `Student`, and `depName` from `Department`.

As of now I am using this query:

```
Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Student.class).createAlias("department", "department");
criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Student.class));

List<Student> rows = (List<Student>)criteria.list();
```

if I try to access rows element for some operation, then it throws

> ClassCastException: java.lang.long or java.lang.string cannot be cast to com.model.Student

Please tell me how to get Student POJO in response of the above query.

Answer (score 0):

You have error here at least

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Student.class).createAlias("departments", "departments");
```

`departments` should be with `S` according to your mapping.